# JQuery Mobile: can't open a popup from a select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open a popup dialog box from a jquery mobile select menu. If I put the popup open command in a timeout it works, but not when directly opening the popup. i.e.:

This works:

```
 $("#message-commands").bind("change", function (event, ui) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    switch (value) {
        case "delete":
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#popupDelete').popup('open');
            }, 1000);
            break;
    }
```

But this does not:

```
$("#message-commands").bind("change", function (event, ui) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    switch (value) {
        case "delete":
            $('#popupDelete').popup('open');
            break;
    }
```

The popupDelete div looks like this

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDelete" style="max-width:300px;" class="ui-corner-all ui-popup ui-body-c ui-overlay-shadow" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" data-transition="none" data-position-to="origin">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-corner-top ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
            <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Delete?</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-d" role="main">
            <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this message?</h3>

        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" onclick="$('#deleteConfirm').popup('close');"><span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span></span></a>   <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-b" onclick="deleteConfirmed();"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Delete</span></span></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? I can't use the above, because if a client is slow to process the command, it will not work within the 1000ms, and I don't want to increase it to make an unreasonable delay for faster clients. I suspect the issue is that the select menu must close first before it can open a popup, but there's no event to detect if a select menu has closed.

Comment: A huge thanks - I was struggling with showing a select menu (JQM 1.2) and your question helped me find the answer - with setTimeOut - a click() method shows the popup

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be, that opening a popup needs some delay, [see also this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153429/in-jquery-mobile-how-would-i-close-a-popup-5-seconds-after-appearing), but why don't you just use a delay of 100ms instead of 1000ms?

Comment: If I use 100ms, then slower clients (e.g. older mobile phones) will not work. FYI, it does work if a put a link on the page, just not when processed from the select menu.

Comment: did you already find a device which is so slow that 1000ms will not be sufficient for the delay? "_it does work if a put a link on the page_" yes I know, however the popup needs some delay if opened otherwise...

Comment: There are 1000s of mobile phones out there so I can't be sure. Regardless, this is not the proper way to do it - delays are arbitrary. The popup does NOT need a delay if I call it by clicking a link on the page. It ONLY needs it if calling from a select menu. If that is not supported, then the select menu should post a "closed" event so it can run properly, i.e. as soon as the menu is closed, not an arbitrary time that I have to guess. If there's no proper solution, I'm going to file a feature request with jqm.